# How to Show Multiple field value according to Row Height

Tags: views, nodes, commerce

[image]

In Content type Having field Work Images and enter the content for that and set the relationship  and CONTEXTUAL FILTERS for the frontend.
Content Is showing fine But its showing random.
How can I show the value as in same order as in backend ?
Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort by the field delta (The position in the list). So in views add "sort criteria" and search for "work images delta"